# Navigation images not displayed properly in jQuery lightbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, vb.net, image

From [this aspcode.net page](http://www.aspcode.net/A-simple-image-gallery.aspx) at the bottom (under attachments) you can download the project.
For some reason when I run it the Close Button and the Next and Previous Buttons don't work. Well I mean it does work but it does not show the actual images. Can anyone figure it out? It should be easy but I just cant get it to work.

Comment: Please ask the author of the article. We cannot possibly know what is wrong.

Comment: Also please consider a question title that is more descriptive of the problem.

Comment: I tried to contact the author, there is no email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths to the URLs in the code start with a / - this means jQuery needs to be in the root of your site.  If this application is running as a virtual directory, remove the leading slash from anywhere that it references the images.

Comment: Cool thanks, but did u get the NEXT and PREV buttons to show?

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved the images to the correct path?

Try using absolute links to the images eg `http://localhost/myimage.jpg` so that you can test that images are really where you say they are.